# Is there a way to stop update on a group repository in Nexus

Tags: nexus

I noticed that whenever my Release/Snapshot Maven repository in nexus is updated i.e a build package is added, the group maven repository updates too. Is this a default behavior? Can this be changed?

Comment: What do you mean your group updates?  The components in them?

Comment: @joedragons : The build package gets added under the group repo too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group repositories are really just pointers to include all the member components. They do not contain any components of their own.  Their real value is 1) to setup one place to pull from rather than multiple and 2) to set an ordering in event of conflict (if you try and pull foo.jar and 2 repositories contain it, it'll take from the first group member containing it).

What you've described is default behavior and cannot be changed except to remove a the repository from the group which would defeat the above stated purposes.

I am not sure which repository version you are on but you can read more about groups [here](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Repository+Management#RepositoryManagement-RepositoryGroup).  The behavior/concept has not changed fundamentally since NXRM2.